# In Apache Ignite, how to control on which node cache is created

Tags: ignite

In ignite, how can I control on which node cache is created? If I need to guarantee one cache is created on all nodes, how can I do that?

Will following codes create cache on all nodes or just some of them?

```
ignite.cluster().forServers().ignite().createCache("myCache")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Ignite creates a cache on the entire set of server nodes.
However it's possible to control that behaviour. There's a mechanism called [node filter](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/managing-data-distribution#node-filter) to choose a subset of nodes to store data for a cache.
What I'm trying to say here is that a cache is created everywhere even by the call:

```java
ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache")
```

To make you compute call collocated you could utilize `affinityCall`. More detailed info can be found [here](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/collocated-computations#colocating-by-key). Example (this lambda is going to be executed on a node storing the `myKey` key):

```java
ignite.compute().affinityCall("myCache", myKey, () -> {
    // do something
    return "something";
})
```

Another option is to [specify](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/distributed-computing/distributed-computing#specifying-the-set-of-nodes-for-computations) a subset of nodes (maybe even just one node) for your computation. Something like that (this lambda is going to be executed on a node with the `nodeId` id):

```java
ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forNodeId(nodeId)).call(() -> {
    // do something
    return "something";
})
```

Comment: so, calling ignite.getOrCreateCache("myCache") will create the cache on all nodes?

Comment: and if I need to execute task on specific node, will this code work?  ignite.cluster().forNodeId(node.id()).ignite.compute().affinityCall()

Comment: @Henrik yes, that's correct. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

In short, to have a cache on all nodes you need to configure [REPLICATED](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#replicated-mode) cache mode. The default mode is [PARTITIONED](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cache-modes#partitioned-mode) one which means data will be spread equally across cluster nodes.

I think configuring [nodeFilters](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/developers-guide/configuring-caches/managing-data-distribution#managing-data-distribution) is the easiest way of adjusting the default behavior, you can say to Ignite which nodes should not keep the data depending on some user-defined node attributes. Please, be aware that you should have a good reason behind changing the default distribution and understand the trade-offs.

Comment: I don't wanna the same data on every node, just wanna make sure one cache is created on every node

Comment: Yes, by default a cache is created on every node. Remember that a cache is basically a set of partitions, 1024 of them by default. Each cache must have a so-called primary partition and its location is determined by an affinity function. The default implementation is RendezvousAffinityFunction https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/cache/affinity/rendezvous/RendezvousAffinityFunction.html Docs: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/data-modeling/data-partitioning#affinity-function